# C - Trouble passing arrays by reference using structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, gtk

I'm trying to pass a 2D char* array, a 1D int array and an integer to a function using a struct, however I am having trouble wrapping my head round how to pass them by reference using pointers, rather than just by value. I need all variables to be editable by the functions they are passed into, and have that value reflected throughout the whole program, not just within the function scope. Essentially like a global variable, but passed from function to function using structs, defined initially in the `main` function.

I initially was using global variables during development, as it worked and it was easy, however I ran into some issues accessing the values in one of the arrays (when accessed from a certain function it would return empty), and I know that global variables are generally a bad idea.

I am using GTK, so as far as I'm aware the only way to pass multiple arguments into a callback is to use structs, hence why I need to pass them via a struct, rather than passing them directly into the function. Unless I'm wrong?

I need to define the following:

```
char* queuedHashes[100][101];
int queuedHashTypes[100] = {(int)NULL};
int hashCount = 0;
```

I've been having trouble understanding the pointer and struct syntax required to achieve this and the methods I have tried have led to me running into the char* array type being `not assignable`, so have not been able to implement anything that works so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you supposed to passed the arrays themselves to the function, or the whole structure?

Comment: Also remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. So to pass e.g. `queuedHashTypes` you could pass it as a plain `int *`, which you can get from the expression `queuedHashTypes`  (which is exactly equal to `&queuedHashTypes[0]`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I need the whole struct passed to the function, as I'm only able to pass one argument into it, and need 3 variables passed in by ref.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve and for what purpose. Maybe you should show some example code that uses global variables and explain what you want to change. Do you want to have a structure that includes these 3 elements and pass a reference to the structure or do you want to have a structure that contains references to these variables that exist independently from the structure? Please [edit] your question to add information or clarification.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the symbolic constant `NULL` is a null *pointer*. C doesn't have the concept or "null" values other than for pointers. If you want to initialize something to zero, then use the number zero.

Comment: Well saying that the only way to pass multiple arguments to a callback works only using structure is wrong and you do not understand the [GObject](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVqhib3eFD68aHowTBjUd2SM) mechanisms. I am strongly recommend you to follow that [GObject](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVqhib3eFD68aHowTBjUd2SM) course and follow all those video and you will find out how to pass N numbers of arguments using only one pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a structure by "reference" (I put it in quotes because C doesn't have "references") you simply pass a pointer to the structure. The contents of the structure is in the memory pointed to by the structure pointer.

So if you have a structure like

```
struct myStruct
{
    char* queuedHashes[100][101];
    int queuedHashTypes[100];
    int hashCount;
};
```

Then you could have a function like

```
void myFunction(struct myStruct *theStructure)
{
    theStructure->queuedHashTypes[0] = 1;
}
```

And use the structure and the function something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct myStruct aStructure;  // Define a structure object

    aStructure.queuedHashTypes[0] = 0;

    printf("Before calling the function queuedHashTypes[0] is %d\n",
           aStructure.queuedHashTypes[0]);

    myFunction(&aStructure);  // Pass a pointer to the structure

    printf("The function initialized queuedHashTypes[0] to %d\n",
           aStructure.queuedHashTypes[0]);
}
```

The program above should print that `queuedHashTypes[0]` is `0` before the function call, and `1` after the call.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm just trying it now. Is there a way to almost 'map' a new name to the struct variables that have been passed into the function? E.g. can I use something like 'variableA[0]' instead of having to write 'theStructure->queuedHashTypes[0]' every time I want to use the variable at index 0, whilst still keeping it referenced to the original variable contained in the struct defined in `main`?

Comment: @JackPollock I don't think that is possible, but if you ask that because you are afraid of the code changes, you could use the find-and-replace function that most text editors have, to do the changes in a bulk

Comment: @Ackdari Thank you for the suggestion. It was more of a neatness thing, was just wondering if it were at all possible, but no worries, find and replace is easy enough to do! Many thanks for your help